# How to parse json files to grab each value using Powershell?

Tags: json, powershell

I have a Powershell script that does an HTTP request and grabs tickets from a queue based on certain groups and then converts each group to a JSON file.  I'm trying to figure out how to parse these to grab values from them so I can then patch them to SQL (the values).  Here is what the JSONs look like:

[image: JSON]

Each array has the same information in each.  I have about 20 of these JSON files, but the arrays are all the same values.  Here is the code I have so far to grab the JSON files, which are in  a foreach:

```
Get-Incidents -assignedGroupin $TeamName -statusIn $statuses | Convertto-JSON | Outfile "C:\pathhere.json"
```

How do I parse the json to grab each value?

Comment: Please (also) post your code, data, error messages as _text_, [not as _images_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/45375).

Comment: Do you actually *need* to serialize them to disk as json, and then read the json back in again, or can you just work with the return value from ```Get-Incidents``` directly?

Comment: I definitely don't but I wasn't sure how to get the info without doing a JSON.  Here is the output file if don't do a JSON:


https://imgur.com/8kZ9Qzr

Comment: I’m not convinced you need to write anything to disk - json or otherwise. To access the properties, try doing something like this: ```$incidents = Get-Incidents -assignedGroupin $TeamName -statusIn $statuses``` and then ```foreach( $incident in $incidents.content ) { write-host $incident.assignedGroupId }```

Comment: Worked perfectly! THanks so much.  I think I was overthinking it lol

Comment: Would there be a way to filter out an array if it contains a certain value?  For example, in this screenshot,  imgur.com/8kZ9Qzr, there is a field (it's not shown in the example screenshot but it's there in every array) called "WorkLogType."  If the WorkLogType is "Web Update," i'd like to filter that whole array out.  Is that possible?